# how to select datetime in sqlite? please help me

Tags: sqlite, flutter, date, datetime, dart

I have value of column

```
datecolumn -> 2021-04-22T00:00:00.000
```

I want select using condition where like below:

```
SELECT * FROM 'tblDOISOAT' where datecolumn = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2021-04-22 00:00:00')
```

I not get được value and i me met error 'Error: near "=": syntax error'. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, but your code works.

```
--------
dt
--------
2021-04-22T00:00:00.000
2021-04-23T01:00:00.000
--------
```

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000', '2021-04-22 00:00:00') as 'datecode'
```

returns `2021-04-22T00:00:00.000`

The query:

```
select dt from 't' where dt= strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000', '2021-04-22 00:00:00')
```

returns the expected result: `2021-04-22T00:00:00.000`

You forgot to include the correct formatting including T and .000 at the end.

*remember that SQLite does not have a datetime data structure by default*. You can read about [SQLite data types here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing date/times as ISO-8601 text, you don't need to call `strftime()` to make comparisons. Just compare the 2 values:

```
select * from t1 where datecol = '2021-04-22T00:00:00.000';
```

The whole point of ISO-8601 strings is to make sure that date/time values compare lexicographically the same as temporally.